# Value Axis Title Click Event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have came across the following example while I have been looking for click event options.

The following example shows when user click on category or numeric axis, it fires up an event.

However I would like to know is there an event when user clicks on the title of value axis (`Dollar($)`) then fires an event.

http://jsfiddle.net/ao617j2j/3/

```
valueAxes: [{
  title: {text: "Dollar($)"},
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Kendo.chart.valueAxis.title doesn't support click events in no way
Kendo.drawing.text that used in chart has no one event

Kendo.drawing.surface has events (and also click event), and i tried use surface instead text
But chart title takes only text!

And i decided create element with event handler manually at chart title place:

http://jsfiddle.net/gf59ru/jfzwuyfw/

```
valueAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: "Dollar($)",
        visual: function (e) {
            var text = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.text, e.rect.origin, {
            });
            if ($('#clickable'))
                $('#clickable').remove();
            $('#example')
            .append('<div id="clickable" onclick="alert(123)" style="position: fixed; top: ' + e.rect.origin.y + 'px; left: ' + e.rect.origin.x + 'px; width: ' + e.rect.size.width + 'px; height: ' + e.rect.size.height + 'px"></div>');
            return text;
        }
    },
}]
```

I lost your title design, and perhaps clickable div position needs to refine

But i hope that this fiddle help you